# How to use Dict to specify type-hint in Python

Tags: python, types, return, python-typing, typing

I have a function which will return a dictionary like:

```
from typing import Dict

def foo() -> Dict[]:
    params = {
        "side": "Buy",
        "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
        "order_type": "Market",
        "time_in_force": "PostOnly",
        "reduce_only": False,
        "close_on_trigger": False,
    }
    return {
        "method": "POST",
        "api": "private/linear/order/create",
        "body": params
    }
```

What should be the content inside `Dict[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this Dict[str, Union[str, Dict]]. The first argument is for the type of the key of the dictionary and the second is the type of the value. In this case, it is non-homogeneous so we need a Union to describe it.

Comment: Adding to this: `Union` will of course need to be imported; also, depending on the Python version you're using, you might be able to use `dict[]` in type hints (3.8+ I think) which would get rid of one import, or even `dict[str, str | bool]` instead of `Union` (3.10+). And if you find yourself typehinting any old JSON, it's often simplest to do `dict[str, Any]`.

Comment: Should I add the details in the second `Dict` ? for example: `Dict[str, Union[str, bool]]`

Answer (score 7):

If the keys of your dictionary are all string and fixed, the [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) in Python3.8+ is very suitable here:

```
from typing import TypedDict


class Params(TypedDict):
    side: str
    symbol: str
    order_type: str
    time_in_force: str
    reduce_only: bool
    close_on_trigger: bool


class Foo(TypedDict):
    method: str
    api: str
    body: Params


def foo() -> Foo:
    params: Params = {
        "side": "Buy",
        "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
        "order_type": "Market",
        "time_in_force": "PostOnly",
        "reduce_only": False,
        "close_on_trigger": False,
    }
    return {
        "method": "POST",
        "api": "private/linear/order/create",
        "body": params
    }
```

Comment: What if I have multiple function which return different kind of dictionary, should I write multiple class for typing like this?

Comment: @tung This depends on your requirements for type hints. If you want to be precise about the type of value corresponding to each key, you can consider doing so.